# How to move to the next highlight?

Tags: highlighting, motion

How can I jump to the next beginning of a string highlighted by a command such as `highlight-regexp` or `highlight-lines-matching-regexp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-u C-s allows you to search for a regexp forward. C-s again recalls the last regexp used.

The following function finds the beginning of the next highlighted region. It prompts for a highlight color so that is not really comfortable. I know it but I do not know the exact circumstance you want to use it. You can easily improve it.

```el
(defun beginning-of-next-highlighted-region (&optional hl)
 "Moves the point before the first following character  that highlighted with the HL highlight or at end of buffer"
  (interactive  (list  (hi-lock-read-face-name) ))
  (while(let ((fc (get-text-property (point)'face) ))
                  (and (consp fc )(memq hl fc) ))
    (forward-char))
  (while (let ((fc (get-text-property (point)'face) ))
                   (or (not (consp fc )) (not (memq hl fc))))
    (forward-char)))
```

You can bind it at any key sequence you want

```el
(bind-key (kbd "C-c h") #'beginning-of-next-highlighted-region)
```

Comment: This is a good idea but I was looking for a highlights-oriented solution to use in conjunction with, for instance, `highlight-lines-matching-regexp`.

Comment: I composed a small function to do the trick.